# RSA encryption in Java and decryption in Python

Tags: java, python, encryption, groovy, rsa

I'm trying to encrypting string in Java and decrypting using Python? Encryption\decryption  in Python works for me, but because I have to use Groovy, I can use Python for encryption.

Groovy ecnryption:

```
def encryption(text) {
   String publicKeyModulus = "MODULUS_GOES_HERE";
   String exponent = "65537";
   RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(publicKeyModulus, 16), new BigInteger(exponent, 10));
   KeyFactory publicKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   publicKey = publicKeyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
   byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

   return cipherData.encodeBase64().toString()
}
```

Python decryption:

```
def decrypt(private_key, data):
  if not private_key:
  raise TypeError("key_path must be specified")

  private_key = base64.b64decode(private_key)
  rsa_key = RSA.importKey(private_key)

  decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
  decrypted = rsa_key.decrypt(decoded)

  return decrypted
```

Decryption returns different result. Any ideas, what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`. If you want more control over the two underlying hash functions, specify `OAEPParameterSpec` similar to this: `cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT))`.

Comment: Are you using pycrypto? Have a look at the decryption [here](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html) and if you switch to OAEP [here](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html).

Comment: Thanks Artjom! Good point. Unfortunately, because I'm using ScriptRunner for Jira, I'm getting meaningless error: "Cannot invoke method matches() on null object" without any stack trace and all objects that I have access are not null, so I won't be able to test your advice, but I think it should fix original problem